# How can I upload files using only Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I want to know how to upload files using Javascript or jQuery.

But not use server side script like php.

If you have some solutions please help me.

Comment: Where would you upload the data when no server side language can be involved?

Comment: You need a server to upload to.

Comment: You can't, server-side code is required. though, i guess you could use node.js, which is javascript but on the server, :p.

Comment: You can't upload a file to your server without a server-side language.

Comment: Are you sure you did mean to "open a file" the file instead of "upload a file"

Comment: Why has no one thought to use magic? Think outside the box, people!

Answer (score 5):

If you mean a normal HTTP file upload: that is not possible. To upload a file to a server, you need a server side language handling the upload and storing the file on its file system.

To my knowledge, there is no implementation of a file transfer protocol like FTP in JavaScript that would allow you to do this without a server side "language" (even though of course the service would have to run).

In theory, it would also be possible to send a file to some API using only JavaScript, but for that, you have to have the API.

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate more on your actual situation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I try to do without using javascript and jquery.But not success.

Answer (score 1):

You will need some kind of server side logic to handle the receipt of the file (otherwise the server will not know what to do with it).

Here is a [demo including source code](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) of how you would implement the 'upload' logic within your browser using jQuery.

Comment: That is using php class to upload files.

Comment: No it's uploading via AJAX... the source linked gives examples of server side code you would need in Python, PHP, or Node.js...

It's impossible to upload a file to a server that isn't configured to receive it... Your *Browser* needs to be able to upload the file and your *Server* needs to be configured to receive the file... These are separate actions that need to be programmed on either side of the interaction.